# Get table names that do not contain "_" in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I am working a script that is supposed to grab a list of table names that contain a specified column, and exclude the table names that contain an underscore. I have tried:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE 
    COLUMN_NAME = 'SERIAL_NUMBER' AND
    TABLE_NAME NOT LIKE '%\_%';
```

This query still pulls table names that contain an underscore. What am I missing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Underscore is a wildcard in LIKE statements - it matches exactly one character.  Try this instead:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'SERIAL_NUMBER' 
AND instr(TABLE_NAME, '_') = 0;
```

---

After posting I noticed that you actually have attempted to escape the underscore.  There is no default escape character for LIKE so you need to tell the database what you're doing:

```
  SELECT TABLE_NAME
FROM USER_TAB_COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'SERIAL_NUMBER' 
AND TABLE_NAME  NOT LIKE '%\_%' ESCAPE '\';
```

[Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions007.htm#sthref2798)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! Thanks for explaining the escape character.

Comment: Don't know whether you've seen my addendum?

Comment: I did, I asked that right before you edited your answer. Thanks for providing a good answer.